# GAE - List does not persist after removing an object (DataNucleus & JDO)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo, datanucleus

I have an entity and one of my properties is an ArrayList of objects, which is serialized. I am trying to delete one of the elements of the list and persist the entity. Everything works fine locally, but not when deployed.

My code:

```
@Inject
public Repository<User> userRepo;
...
Leader leader = (Leader) item.getModelObject();
...
MySession.get().getUser().getLeaders().remove(leader);
JDOHelper.makeDirty(MySession.get().getUser(), "leaders");
userRepo.persist(MySession.get().getUser());
```

property definition in User entity:

```
@Persistent(defaultFetchGroup = "true", serialized = "true")
@Extension(vendorName = "datanucleus", key = "gae.unindexed", value = "true")
private ArrayList<Leader> leaders = new ArrayList<Leader>();
```

I am using datanucleus-core version 1.1.6, jdo2-api 2.3-eb and datanucleus-appengine 1.0.10

It works fine when I add new items to the list, but not when I remove something - why is it so? And how can I make it work?

Comment: Please show your code. Without seeing code, we can at best only speculate and make only uneducated guesses.

Comment: Ok, I have updated my question with more details. I hope it is enough.

Comment: I used to have a lot of trouble with datanucleus quitely deciding for itself not to save an object. You can see these object states & decisions in FINE level logs

Comment: I was pretty sure that making something dirty would force it to save always...

Comment: I've found that I have to extract the collection from the object and then re-add the entire collection using a setter property. In other words, I haven't had luck calling remove without instantiating a new collection and then using the setter on the object to set the collection back on it.  Try calling remove and then resetting your object in the user object and then setting the user in the MySession. It's possible that DataNucleus can't handle the fact that the object was modified within the session. This part is of course pure speculation on my part, which is why it's a comment not an answer

Comment: jmort253: I have tried doing that - I have created temporary object obtained from getLeaders(), then I removed one position from it, then I used that value fot setLeaders, but result was the same - still no change in database. It's something about high replication nature of GAE and how DataNucleus interacts with it probably. Because of that I had to call makeDirty when I was adding something to the collection. I have no idea why it isn't working on removing an item from collection.

Comment: Any exceptions from cranking that log level up to FINE or ALL?

Comment: Nothing really on fine, it says there is one dirty object, but I am also modifying other value in that entity, so it should be 2 dirty objects. Weird that following works:

MySession.get().getUser().getLeaders().add(newLeader);
JDOHelper.makeDirty(MySession.get().getUser(), "leaders");      userRepo.persist(MySession.get().getUser());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making something dirty makes it dirty and nothing more; persist/flush happens after ... start of next transaction (as per JDO/JPA spec) or close of PM/EM; no call to makePersistent/persist will change that. This isn't DataNucleus "deciding for itself" not to persist an object, it's simply following the spec.

If you use recent GAE releases (v2.0) you can have non-transactional atomic persist/delete (extension to the specs). If you use SVN trunk (v2.1) you can also have nontransactional atomic updates (extending it further still). i.e with latest code you have the equivalent of JDBC "autocommit"

Comment: I am aware that there must be some logic behind it, my knowledge about everything surrounding it is quite limited though.

Is 2.0 version stable enough? I remember only beta version of it. I am certainly going to upgrade in the future, as my version is really ancient, when it comes to DataNucleus functionality.

How can I achieve what I want in current version that? That is how to make sure that all changes are saved when I persist an object? Because the object is persisting, it's just the problem with collections/serialized fields not being persisted then.

Comment: 2.x passes more tests than Googles v1.x so that is "stable" in my book ;-) What would work with v1.0 I can't really answer, only guess at ... Google wrote that version of their plugin. Try a txn around it? Try putting a txn begin/commit just after. Look at the log and see what happens a). at making it dirty, b). at start/commit of the txn.

Comment: I guess updating to 2.x will be my best option then.